# has_many and belongs_to nameerror rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my `index_controller`

```
  def index
    @category = Category.all
  end
```

My category model contains

`has_many :sub_categories`

and my sub_category model contains

`belongs_to :category`

And here is my view

```
<% category.sub_categories.each do |f| %>
    <li>f.name</li>
<% end %>
```

I am using rails 4 and am getting error as

```
undefined local variable or method `category' for #<#<Class:0xab758cc>:0xb56c46d8>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just a little bit off with your naming conventions and what sort of code it prompts you to write:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

`@category` should be `@categories`, because `Category.all` will return an ActiveRecord Relation of 0, 1 or many Category objects, not a single object.

Then:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <% category.sub_categories.each do |sub_category| %>
    <li><%= sub_category.name %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end >
```

First you iterate over the categories from `Category.all`, then for each Category, you iterate over its SubCategories.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems there.

- It should be `@category`, not `category`
- It should be `<li><%= f.name %></li>`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the reference to the instance variable and the `ERB` tag to use `f.name`, it should be

```
<% @category.sub_categories.each do |f| %>
  <li><%= f.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No this is `NoMethodError`

Comment: I was about to ask the same, it is weird to return a `NoMethodError` here, this first part is ok, something broke ahead.

Comment: Yeah sure, you missed the `ERB` tag when inside the form, try to put `<li><%= f.name %></li>`. Edited the answer to add this.